# Which software is best for logos and shapes designing

Tags: software-rec, graphics-editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Logo Editing Software For Non-Techie](https://superuser.com/questions/14013/logo-editing-software-for-non-techie)

I am finding it very difficult to use photoshop for designing something new like logos new pics etc.

I want to know which software should i learn in which i can create new logos and shapes.

Also which software is used to make photos like these

http://depositphotos.com/2594857/s31340372/stock-photo-Abstract-network-illustration.html

Answer (score 0):

It has to be something which handles Vectors, so that you can blow up your logo when required. That counts out simple programs like Paint.Net.

I've been a fan of Paint Shop Pro for a long time, and still use an old version. But then again, I don't do enough graphics work to justify paying much money for graphics software, and a professional will probably ask what trouble you're having with Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/)

> An Open Source vector graphics editor, with capabilities similar to
>   Illustrator, CorelDraw, or Xara X, using the W3C standard Scalable
>   Vector Graphics (SVG) file format.

[image]